# SSRS cascading parameters for SSAS Tabular datasource with M2M relationship between dimensions in SQL Server 2014 BI

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssas-tabular

I'm trying to build a simple report using SSAS Tabular model as datasource. There are two different dimensions in the model - UserGroups that should be used as first parameter and Regions as second one. These dimensions are M2M-related in the model. Simple measure calculated with the usage of M2M tricks for tabular models works fine in Excel and PBID.

I need those parameters to be cascaded in SSRS report. I.e. Regions dropdown should be filtered after selecting one ore more (Allow multiple values parameter option is ON) values in UserGroups dropdown.

After I put both dimension onto Filter pane in Query Designer I receive two parameters with hidden datasets. Everything looks fine but first parameters (UserGroups) actually do not filter Regions dropdown.

I think I understand the nature of the issue. We see the same picture in other client tools like Excel when placing M2M-related dimensions on the same rows/columns pane - second dimension displays in the Pivot Table all its members until we check a measure in Pivot Table Fields. All the members for the second dimension (Regions in my case) are vanished as soon as a measure comes into play - Excel is smart enough to wipe out dimension members if the measure value is null. But this does not happen in SSRS.

All the "automatic" cascading parameters creation works well within hierarchies of a single dimension. I hope this works as well with one-to-many related dimensions. But how can I extend/modify automagically-created MDX query for the second parameter dataset  to be filtered out? It looks like `SELECT ( StrToSet ( @[UserGroupsUserGroups], CONSTRAINED ) ) ON COLUMNS` is not enough in this case. I need also to check measure value to filter out Regions list. Unfortunately I'm not an MDX expert. Please help me to inject this checking into the query.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track and gave a good explanation of the scenario. As you found out, there is no automatic way to make the parameters cascade. You do need to add an MDX filter to the second parameter to make this happen.

As far as the actual query is concerned, there's not quite enough information to give you an exact query. But you would use `StrToSet` to pass in the first parameter and use the `FILTER` function to limit the scope. As you stated, including a measure is one way to get only the "NonEmpty" combinations of the two parameters. If you run into a specific problem with a sample query, feel free to provide more details on that.